# D3 path missing height elements

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I create flat line in  using d3

```
<path d="M76.75,75.00981241717429L230.25,75.00981241717429L383.75, 
75.00981241717429L537.25,75.009812417174291" stroke="#657DBB" class="line" 
style="stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-width: 5; stroke-opacity: 1;">
```

Draws lines but in devtools have `0px` `height` and when I use `mask` for limiting drawing area, mask covers all `0px` `elements`,  someone can help ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% what you are asking, or trying to do. `path` elements don't have a height. They simply draw a line that has a width defined by `stroke-width`.

Comment: @lemming `<path>` elements certainly don't have a `height` attribute (like a `<rect>` does), but they do have a height, the same way they have a width.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the expected result. For calculating the bounding box of an element the `.getBBox()` method is used. The behavior of `.getBBox` is defined by the SVG spec in [4.5.23 Interface SVGLocatable](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) (emphasis mine):

> Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all contained graphics elements, **exclusive of stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects**).

Since all the y-coordinates of your path's move and line-to commands equal `75.00981241717429` the height of the bounding as defined by the spec obviously is zero.

Comment: I don't know why the SVG commission chose to exclude the stroke. In my opinion the stroke is part of the element, and therefore should be included in `getBBox`, `getBoundingClientRect` etc...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Given how the rest of the SVG 1.1 spec is made up I tend to prefer it as it is. It's more rigorous. Nonetheless, I clearly understand the need for a *visual* bounding box which, BTW, amongst others also needs to take into account markers. This burden might eventually be lifted from our sholders once (or if) the days comes when SVG 2 is released into the wild, which has a notion of *object bounding box* (today's bbox), *stroke bounding box*, and *decorated bounding box*: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#BoundingBoxes ...

Comment: ...These boxes will be available by passing optional `SVGBoundingBoxOptions` to [`SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGGraphicsElement). E.g., `element.getBBox({ stroke: true })` will include stroking. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: I hope so, but I believe SVG 2 will never be properly *released*. What's going to happen is that browsers will slowly and independently start supporting individual, separated features of SVG 2, in a disorganised way, making our life very hard.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I was delighted to see Amelia Bellamy-Royds's name on top of the list of editors. I just recently stumbled upon her post reflecting on her future work and her participations in the standardization of SVG 2. Unfortunately, for now, my tests on Chrome and FF have shown that neither browser support the new API.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It actually works in FF: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lumt814/ Provided you enabled the `svg.new-getBBox.enabled` preference. No luck in Chrome and Edge, though...

Comment: it seems that Firefox is slowly implementing SVG2 features... have a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423049/5768908).

Comment: By the way, we have 2 "Edges" now: the old, Windows 10 Edge and the new, Chromium-based Edge. I'm testing the Chromium-based Edge on MacOS (it was released for Windows as well), it's way better! I wonder if Microsoft will automatically replace the Edge on Windows 10 machines for the new Chromium-based Edge.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Still a long way to go, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_2_support_in_Mozilla